# WordNet 3.0 Curse Words

Tags: mysql, lexical-analysis, wordnet

I'm developing a system where keywords are extracted from plain text.

The requirements for a keyword are:

1. Between 1 - 45 letters long
2. Word must exist within the WordNet database
3. Must not be a "common" word
4. Must not be a curse word

I have fulfilled requirements 1 - 3, however I can't find a method for finding a distinction between curse words; how do I filter them?

I know this would not be a definitive method of filtering out all the curse words, but what happens is all keywords are first set to a state of "pending" before being "approved" by a moderator. However if I can get WordNet to filter most of the curse words out, it would make the moderator's job more easy.

Comment: Fundamentally, you just need to find a list of "vulgar" words to filter against.

Answer (score 4):

It's strange, the Unix command line version of WordNet (wn) will give you the desired
information with the option -domn (domain):

```
wn ass -domnn (-domnv for a verb)

...
>>> USAGE->(noun) obscenity#2, smut#4, vulgarism#1, filth#4, dirty word#1
>>> USAGE->(noun) slang#2, cant#3, jargon#1, lingo#1, argot#1, patois#1, vernacular#1
```

However, the equivalent method in the NLTK just returns an empty list:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
a = wordnet.synsets('ass')
for s in a:
    for l in s.lemmas:
        print l.usage_domains()
        
[]
[]
...
```

As an alternative you could try to filter words that have "obscene", "coarse" or "slang" in their SynSet's definition. But probably it's much easier to filter against a fixed list as suggested before (like the one at [noswearing.com](http://www.noswearing.com/dictionary)).

Answer (score 0):

For the 4th point it would be better and effective if you can collect the list of curse words and remove them through iterative process.

To achieve the same you can checkout [this](http://bastian.rieck.ru/blog/posts/2015/enron_swear_words/) blog

I will summarize the same here.
 1. Load Swear words text file from [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/bad-words.txt)
 2. Compare it with the text, remove if it match.

```
def remove_curse_words():
    text = 'Hey Bro Fuck you'
    text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in curseWords])
    return text
```

The output would be.

> Hey bro you